# Spring State Machine - Why documentation use static classes

Tags: java, spring, static-classes, spring-statemachine

In [Spring Statemachine](https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/) the main example use `static` classes for `@Configuration`

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableStateMachine
> static class Config1 extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {
> ```

And Beans

> ```
> @WithStateMachine
> static class MyBean {
> ```

Also using `@Autowired`:

> ```
> static class MyApp {
>    @Autowired
>    StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;
> ```

Is it old/sample documentation that can be ignored or is there a real reason/need to use static classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it old/sample documentation that can be ignored or is there a real
>   reason/need to use static classes?

Yes.

No need for statics - check out the recent examples in the Appendices -> Quick Example - https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/#quick-example and even in the pre-release 3.0.0M1 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/3.0.0.M1/reference/#appendices

Comment: Thank you, is it wrong to use static class when using Spring DI?

Comment: From the context of the question I would assume you mean static classes annotated with @Configuration - keep in mind those are inner (nested) classes - it is not wrong. It's a common pattern to have different configurations for the same component bundled together in a class and defined in a separate static inner classes (e.g. For component X - static Configuration A (for local usage) and static Configuration B (for prod usage) etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the annotations `@EnableStateMachine` and `@EnableStateMachineFactory` they doesn't have to be static. However if you don't use those annotations and want to build and configure it you must use static.

> All features for @WithStateMachine can be enabled by using annotation @EnableWithStateMachine which simply imports needed configuration into Spring Application Context. Both @EnableStateMachine and @EnableStateMachineFactory are already annotated with this so there is no need for user to add it again. However if machine is build and configured without a use of configuration adapters, @EnableWithStateMachine must be used order to use features with @WithStateMachine. Idea for this is shown below...

Check this documentation: [StateMachine](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sm-context.html)

Comment: But also `@EnableStateMachine` is on static class and your quote has no static reference

Comment: What i was trying to say is that they don't need to be static. Sometimes State Machine must be created dinamically and this is impossible to achived if you use a static definition at compile time.